# SQL Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 498 Ambiguous column name 'SupplyCode'

Tags: sql

I can't seem to solve the error no matter what I do.

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 498
>   Ambiguous column name 'SupplyCode'.

--h.    Select the supply code and description of the supplies that have never been used on a job.(2 marks)

```
select SupplyCode,Description, count(*) from JobSupply

inner join Supply
on Supply.SupplyCode = JobSupply.SupplyCode

group by Supply.SupplyCode
```

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 498
Column 'Supply.Description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is what i had orignallay done 
select Supply.SupplyCode,Description,count(jobNumber) from Supply

inner join JobSupply
on Supply.SupplyCode = JobSupply.SupplyCode

group by Supply.SupplyCode

having Count(JobNumber) = 0

Comment: you need to prefix the alias or table name for `SupplyCode`: `SELECT Supply.SupplyCode .....`

Comment: i tired that, but it refueses to run

Comment: what does "refuses to run" mean?

Comment: well, you need to also add `Description` to the `GROUP BY` dude: `GROUP BY Supply.SupplyCode, description`

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify SupplyCode in the selected columns as it cannot disambiguate from the SupplyCode in Supply and the SupplyCode in JobSupply. Try:

```
select S.SupplyCode,Description, count(*) from JobSupply
inner join Supply S on S.SupplyCode = JobSupply.SupplyCode
group by S.SupplyCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the column `SupplyCode` exists in both referenced tables you have to qualify the name in the select statement and specify which table it should be retrieved from.

You might consider using aliases too:

```
select s.SupplyCode, Description, count(*) 
from JobSupply js
join Supply s on s.SupplyCode = js.SupplyCode
group by s.SupplyCode, description
```

On a side note, the query you provided probably won't answer the question you are trying to solve. (*Select the supply code and description of the supplies that have never been used on a job*)

You probably want to use a left join and filter out the missing rows as those should be the ones that have never been used. Or you could use a correlated subquery with the `exists` predicate:

Something like this:

```
select SupplyCode, Description 
from Supply s
where not exists (select 1 from jobsupply js where s.SupplyCode = js.SupplyCode)
```

Comment: i thought it would be somthing like that ...  i am still having an error, but i think i m closer ... thank you so much ...

Comment: @Lost It might be that your second query could work if you change the join type from inner to left.

Comment: i tried that .... its okay ill try and see if my prof will help me.....  thank you for yourhelp though